# Facebook lead forms directly into website/api

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm currently running some facebook advertising which includes lead forms directly in facebook.

We also have a website, which I've built in the CURL function to send the data via XML to the end clients API.

What I'm looking to achieve is that we can automate the facebook leads into the API itself, so for example, if someone fills out the facebook lead form - is there anyway we can get that to auto populate the web form on the website and then submit it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks